# Is it possible to to rollover 401K into an IRA account multiple times with different employers?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, rollover, rollover-ira

Say I am employed with company 'A' with whom I have a 401K account. Now, while switching jobs, I decide not to carry forward this 401K to the next employer but instead rollover this 401K I had with company 'A' into a rollover IRA, which I later convert to a Roth IRA.

Now, say I am with my new employer 'B'. When I switch my job again, can I once again rollover this 401K (I have with employer 'B') into the my rollover IRA account and later convert it to Roth IRA?

This process is more like a backdoor to having an IRA account if your income is above the state specified limits. Therefore, if such multiple rollovers are possible, how many such rollovers are allowed?

Comment: Just be aware that even if you have a Roth 401(k) only -- which can be rolled over tax-free into a Roth IRA -- your _employer match_ (if any) is in a pre-tax account and will be rolled over into a Traditional IRA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe there is any real limitation. [This IRS web page is instructive.](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/rollovers-of-retirement-plan-and-ira-distributions)

Note that the limit of one rollover per year appears to apply when you have received a distribution from another IRA and want to put it into another IRA.

Note:

> The one-per year limit does not apply to:
>
> - **rollovers from traditional IRAs to Roth IRAs (conversions)**
> - trustee-to-trustee transfers to another IRA
> - IRA-to-plan rollovers
> - **plan-to-IRA rollovers**
> - **plan-to-plan rollovers**

where I've bolded the items that seem to apply in your case.

Comment: Note that you still need to pay income tax on a Traditional-to-Roth conversion, and it counts as regular income, which may push you into a higher tax bracket.

Comment: It seems clear that this question is talking about rollovers from 401(k)s into IRAs (which are plan-to-IRA rollovers). So the first two items in the list (the ones you've bolded) definitely don't seem to apply in this case, but the fourth item does apply.

Comment: @TannerSwett D'oh! You're right. Will update. Thanks!